# NMDA receptor depolarization

Tags: cell-biology, neuroscience, physiology, neurophysiology

I learnt that two factors for NMDA receptor channels opening are:

1)Binding of glutamate

2)Depolarization of postsynaptic cell (to remove the Mg+2 block)

Given that depolarization starts in axon hillock and NMDA receptors are on dendrites, how does it all work?

Comment: "depolarization starts in axon hillock" - this is not true, why do you think this?

Comment: Seemingly I confused the term with action potential. So NMDA receptors need a depolarization which is below +30?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also read about backpropagating action potentials.

Comment: Alright, I will. Thank you!